# Update array without using $push in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
this._MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email },
    {
      $set: {
        'tradeAccount': {
          limitType,
          limit,
        }
      },
      $push: {
        'tradeAccount.history': history
      }
    }
  );
```

I want to add another object into an existing array using `$push` but in the same time I am performing another update on the same object using `$set`.

I know that I cannot use two operators on the same field such as (`$set` and `$push`).

I wonder if there is another way to add another object into an existing array using `$set`, or if there is any other way to do this in the same update request.

I was thinking of updating the array using `$set` by retrieving the existing history and concatenate with the new one. But that requires an extra call to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
this._MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { email },
  {
    $set: {
      'tradeAccount'.'limitType': limitType,
      'tradeAccount'.'limit': limit
    },
    $push: {
      'tradeAccount.history': history
    }
  }
);
```

This should update the limitType and limit fields, and then push onto history. You aren't performing multiple queries on the same field this way because you aren't doing anything directly to 'tradeAccount'.

Comment: Seems like something that worths trying.  I already separated the history update from user update, because I think this approach follows closely the `S`OLID principle. Thank you!